# Displaying LDAP errors in UI

Tags: java, ldap

Currently I have code that is used to change a password that is stored on an LDAP server. I am using a boolean variable to store the result if the update was successful or not, thereafter I check if the update failed via an `if` statement and I display an error message.

The issue I'm facing is how can I display more specific errors in the UI if the password change fails?

For example:

- The existing password is invalid
- The username is incorrect
- The account has been locked

If someone could please advise on what could be a nice and tidy solution to my problem. Below is a snippet of the reset password method:

```
boolean passwordReset = this.userManagement.update(this.username, this.resetPassword, this.resetOldPassword);

if(!passwordReset){
        super.addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,super.getResource("password.error"), super.getResource("user.password.change.error"));

} else {
    super.addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,super.getResource("change.password.head"), super.getResource("password.changed.success"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should modify the `userManagement.update` method to raise an exception in case of error. So depending on the error it could throw `InvalidPasswordException`, `UsernameException`, `BlockedAccoutException`, etc. or just throw an only exception with a custom message.
In any case, first you need to collect this information from the ldap operation.

Example code:

```
try {
  this.userManagement.update(this.username, this.resetPassword, this.resetOldPassword);

} catch(InvalidPasswordException e) {
  super.addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, super.getResource("password.error"), super.getResource("user.password.change.error"));
} catch(UsernameException e) {
  super.addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, super.getResource("username.error"), super.getResource("user.name.error"));
} catch(BlockedAccoutException e) {
  super.addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, super.getResource("blockaccount.error"), super.getResource(blockaccount.error"));
}
```

Or:

```
try {
  this.userManagement.update(this.username, this.resetPassword, this.resetOldPassword);
} catch(UpdateUserException e) {
  super.addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, super.getResource(e.getErrorCode()));
}
```

The problem with the first approach is that you have to create several (or a lot) of classes. 
This doesn't happen with the second option, but you need a way to get the proper error message. You may add an error type/code to the exception.

Comment: cool sounds like a good plan , It does throw an exception , I would want to go with the option of throwing one exception for each case , how do you catch these exception though?

Comment: Thanks alot , I already went with the first option and it seems to work perfectly , much appreciated.